# Prove that the minimum of a functional doesn't exist

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

Prove that there is no smooth solution ho the minimization problem:

$$\mathcal{L} (u)= \int_{0}^1 e^{-u'}+u^2 dx$$

Where the admissible space is $X =\{ u \in \mathcal{c}^2 [0,1] | u(0)=0,  u(1)=1
       \} $

UPDATE:

GOAL: I am trying to define a sequence of functions $u_n(x)$ in $X$ s.t their integrals $\mathcal{L}(u_n) \to 0$

What I have done so far:

Define $u_n(x)$ in the following manner:
$$u_n (x)= \begin{cases}
0, \quad 0 \leq x\leq 1-\frac{1}{n} \\[2ex]
ax^2 +bx+ c, \quad 1-\frac{1}{n}<x \leq 1 
\end{cases}$$

where $n=1,2,3,..$. Require that $u_n$ satisfy:
\begin{align}
 u_n(1-\frac{1}{n})=0\\
 u_n(1)=1\\
 u_n'(1-\frac{1}{n})=0\\
\end{align}

We then have:
\begin{align}
a+b+c=1\\
a(1-\frac{1}{n})^2+b(1-\frac{1}{n})+c=0\\
2a(1-\frac{1}{n})+b=0 
\end{align}

Find $a,b,c$ then:

$$u_n (x)= \begin{cases}
0, \quad 0 \leq x\leq 1-\frac{1}{n} \\[2ex]
n^2x^2 -2n(n-1)x+ (n-1)^2, \quad 1-\frac{1}{n}<x \leq 1 
\end{cases}$$

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 e^{-u_n(x)'} + u_n^2(x) dx &= \int_0^{1-\frac{1}{n}} e^{0} + 0 dx +  \int_{1-\frac{1}{n}}^1 e^{-(2n^2 x -2n(n-1))} + (n^2x^2 -2n(n-1)x+ (n-1)^2)^2 dx\\& = 1- \dfrac{1}{n}+ \dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-2n}\left(\left(2n+5\right)\mathrm{e}^{2n}-5\right)}{10n^2}
\end{align}

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-2n}\left(\left(2n+5\right)\mathrm{e}^{2n}-5\right)}{10n^2} \to 0$$ and $$1-\dfrac{1}{n} \to 1$$

Comment: This question looks very similar <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200505/show-that-a-functional-has-no-minimum-in-a-given-set>.

Comment: I don't think the answer is correct. I don't want to use the E-L equation.

Comment: @Véronique: Any particular reason you want to avoid the E-L equation? I'd suggest making this explicit in the post, since it's probably the first thing most people would think to use (also the E-L tag could be confusing if you don't want it applied here).

Comment: Good insight noticing the integral in nonnegative. One approach to this kind of problem is to find a sequence of functions satisfying the constraints, in this case $v \in C^2[0, 1]$, $v(0) = 1$, $v(1) = 1$. The functional/integral decreases to a minimum, yet the sequence doesn't converge in $C^2[0, 1]$. Maybe think about $v_n(x) = x^n$ and clever bounding?

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): The sign in the exponential and the boundary conditions are different from [the other Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2200505/11127).

Answer (score 0):

We can more or less use the same proof technique as in my Math.SE answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2212126/11127).

1. Define function $$f(a)~:=~(a+1)e^{-a}.\tag{1}$$
   Now it is a fact that
   $$ \exists ! a_0 <0:~~ f(a_0)~=~0. \tag{2}$$
   $$ \forall a> a_0: ~~ 0~<~f(a)~\leq~1.\tag{3}$$
   $$ \forall a< a_0: ~~ f(a)~<~0.\tag{4}$$
   Here $a_0=-1$. There is a [first](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BeltramiIdentity.html) [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity) to OP's EL equation. Together with OP's boundary conditions, it becomes $$  f(u^{\prime}(0))~=~ f(u^{\prime}) + u^2 
   ~=~f(u^{\prime}(1))+1 .\tag{5} $$
   In light of eqs. (2)-(4) we see that eq. (5) is impossible to satisfy for $u^{\prime}(1)>a_0$ because then $f(u^{\prime}(1))>0$ while $f(u^{\prime}(0))\leq 1$.
2. The EL equation reads
   $$ \left(-e^{-u^{\prime}}\right)^{\prime}~=~2u.\tag{6} $$
   If in the interval $[x_0,1]$ the function $u > 0$ is positive, then $-e^{-u^{\prime}}$ (and thereby $u^{\prime}$) is increasing, and hence $u^{\prime}\geq 0$. Then
   $$u^{\prime}(1)~\geq~ 0,\tag{7}$$
   which according to section 1 leads to a contradiction. $\Box$

Comment: How is (7) contradicting $u'(1)>-1$ ?

Answer (score -1):

Observe that you cannot have $\mathcal{L}(u)=0$, since that would imply $u=0$ a.e., which contradicts the fact that $u(1)=1$ (+continuity). Therefore, $\mathcal{L}(u)>0$ for all $u\in X$.
As someone already mentioned, you can consider the sequence $u_n(x)=x^n$, which satisfies $\mathcal{L}(u_n)\to 0$ (by the dominated convergence theorem).
This implies that $\mathcal{L}$ does not attain its minimum on $X$.

Comment: $L(u_{n})$ does not converge to $0$ for $u_{n} = x^{n}$.